# Excel formula returning number values when I want it to return "-"

Tags: excel

I am kind of new to this type of Excel formula but from what I can see we want the formula to return "-"if it finds the value "mi adidas" but it seems to be returning a value and doing this across three columns - not the best at excel so any help would be great. Maybe we are missing something easy?

=IFERROR(COUNTIF(PCNS!$J:$J;"mi adidas");"-")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Countif will always return a value. It will only return an error if there is an error in the range it looks into.

IfError returns the second parameter if the first parameter returns an error.

If you want to return a "-" sign when Countif actually finds something, then try

```
=if(COUNTIF(PCNS!$J:$J;"mi adidas");"-";"")
```

In words: if the count of the range for "mi adidas" is greater than 0, return a "-" otherwise return nothing.

A comparison like `>0` is not needed, since any number greater than zero will be interpreted as TRUE.

Answer (score 0):

maybe:

```
IF(COUNTIF(PCNS!$J:$J;"mi adidas")>0;"-";"")
```

if count of "mi adidas" in J column be greater than 0 formula return "-" in other case formula return "" (nothing - zero-char string)

Comment: **From review queue:** May I request you to please add some more context around your answer. Code-only answers are difficult to understand. It will help the asker and future readers both if you can add more information in your post. See also [Explaining entirely code-based answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers).